# Replicating Excel cell formulae in R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have little experience with R. I am not sure how to do the following calculations in R, should I imitate Excel or there is a better way to do the simple Excel cell subtraction.

I have the following data in R.

```
year    marketplace bridged_on  value
01/01/2018  US  A    1,710,103,328 
01/01/2018  US  B    1,710,103,328 
01/01/2018  US  C    1,710,103,328 
01/01/2018  US  D    1,710,103,328 
01/01/2019  US  A    1,669,210,438 
01/01/2019  US  B    1,653,940,292 
01/01/2019  US  C    1,624,487,359 
01/01/2019  US  D    1,617,335,174 
01/01/2020  US  A    1,674,636,402 
01/01/2020  US  B    1,647,437,876 
01/01/2020  US  C    1,601,234,000 
01/01/2020  US  D    1,591,107,584
```

I need to calculate change year-over-year and in Excel, I am creating a pivot table that has years as columns and then applying a subtraction formula across cells.

This is a screenshot from calculations done in Excel. I am calculating the difference between A and B, B and C, C and D and then subtracting the same difference from the previous year. For example, the calculation in H6  is (C6-C7)-(D6-D7).

I am not sure how to reproduce the same calculation in R and have G5 to H8 as an output in R.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried anything with `tidyr::spread` or `data.table::dcast`? (I'd recommend those two as a starting place before `reshape2::` functions ... probably `tidyr` first.)

Answer (score 0):

### Prepare and clean data

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(readr)
library(reshape2)

data <- read_delim("year    marketplace bridged_on  value
01/01/2018  US  A    1,710,103,328 
01/01/2018  US  B    1,710,103,328 
01/01/2018  US  C    1,710,103,328 
01/01/2018  US  D    1,710,103,328 
01/01/2019  US  A    1,669,210,438 
01/01/2019  US  B    1,653,940,292 
01/01/2019  US  C    1,624,487,359 
01/01/2019  US  D    1,617,335,174 
01/01/2020  US  A    1,674,636,402 
01/01/2020  US  B    1,647,437,876 
01/01/2020  US  C    1,601,234,000 
01/01/2020  US  D    1,591,107,584 ",delim = " ")

colnames(data) <- str_trim(colnames(data))
data <- map_dfc(data,str_trim)

data <- data %>%
    mutate(year= mdy(year),
           value = parse_number(value))
```

```
#display cleaned data

> data 
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   year       marketplace bridged_on      value
   <date>     <chr>       <chr>           <dbl>
 1 2018-01-01 US          A          1710103328
 2 2018-01-01 US          B          1710103328
 3 2018-01-01 US          C          1710103328
 4 2018-01-01 US          D          1710103328
 5 2019-01-01 US          A          1669210438
 6 2019-01-01 US          B          1653940292
 7 2019-01-01 US          C          1624487359
 8 2019-01-01 US          D          1617335174
 9 2020-01-01 US          A          1674636402
10 2020-01-01 US          B          1647437876
11 2020-01-01 US          C          1601234000
12 2020-01-01 US          D          1591107584
```

### TO answer your question

I believe your calculation on row 8 is wrong though. You're calculating using the grand total according to the formula you provides.

To do it in R, you need to structure the data frame in **long format** and use `dplyr::lag()` to calculate difference between different years. Finally, you need to use `reshape2::dcast()` to convert from long format to wide format.

You can break down the pipes and see what's the intermediate result in each step.

```r
result <- data %>%
    mutate(year = year(year)) %>%
    group_by(bridged_on) %>%
    mutate(annual_diff = value - lag(value)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(annual_diff)) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    mutate(annual_diff2 = annual_diff - lag(annual_diff)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(annual_diff2)) %>%
    select(year,bridged_on,annual_diff2) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    dcast(bridged_on ~ year)
```

```r
>result
  bridged_on      2019      2020
1          B -15270146 -11928380
2          C -29452933 -16750943
3          D  -7152185  -2974231
```